# scanimage gives error when trying to scan

Tags: scanner

I used to have my scanner working ok via commandline using a command similar to `ramy@moonface:~$ scan -d pixma:04A9172B_D05FD9 --format jpeg`

Now, after upgrading to ubuntu 22.04, I get the following error message:

`scanimage: output is not a file, exiting`

The scan-bed is not getting activated so i'm not sure at all what's happening.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you in the same group as the scanner in `/dev` directory?  `id` to see your groups, also watch `sudo  journalctl  --follow` as you plug in the scanner.

Comment: @waltinator, could you elaborate on what I'm looking for in `journalctl` output? I did find: `Nov 13 19:58:33 moonface /hpfax[20184]: [20184]: error: Failed to create /var/spool/cups/tmp/.hplip`  I'm also not entirely clear on how to a.) tell which directory corresponds to the scanner in `/dev` or b.) how to read the output from `id`.

Comment: @waltinator how can I tell which device is the scanner in `/dev`?

Comment: Disconnect the scanner; do `ls -l /dev >before`; connect the scanner; wait 10 seconds; do `ls -l /dev >after`. Then, `diff before after`.

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you OFF/ON the scanner.